# HTML Links Not Clickable in Mobile Email Campaigns

Tags: html, email, html-email

I've just encountered a new issue that hasn't popped up in the 2.5 years I've been doing it. I send emails using Mailchimp and use HTML coding to format. Recently, my email campaigns have been clickable on desktop but spotty on mobile. Certain images will be clickable, certain ones won't - and when I return to the email, some new images are clickable or sometimes no images are clickable. It's very random. Below is an example of how I have always coded my emails. [Picture of Code Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsFz1.png)

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We don't debug images.

Comment: This is definitely code related, though please don't provide a picture of the code; rather, copy the actual code into the question (use the code sample button near the bold and italic buttons, { } to format correctly)

Comment: Please copy and peaste your code here on SO instead of using pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an area map to get precise locations on an image to link. However, on mobiles, those images are getting shrunk, depending on their size. Every email platform will shrink them differently, and depending on the content of the email, and the size of the images, they will shrink to different sizes.

So that explains the discrepancy you see. Now how to solve it?

Essentially, instead of providing one massive image, you need to use HTML + CSS, with tables and separate images and links. You need to lookup any modern resource on HTML emails and follow their guides or templates. This way, when the images move around to fit on mobiles, each image or word will have it's own link, and it will work consistently.